# How to make the program continues even if the value is null

Tags: java, mysql, image, null, imageicon

I have a program here in java and MySQL for database. However the problem is: when the data for IMAGE in the SQL is null, the program stops loading picture.
It shows "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!". My question is how will I able to set the Icon picture as null and continue.

```
  try{
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(President);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
        rs.absolute(1);
        FirstName1.setText(rs.getString("cFirstname"));
        LastName1.setText(rs.getString("CLastname"));
        MiddleName1.setText(rs.getString("cmiddlename"));
        BufferedImage im1 = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("cimage"));
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(im1);
        Image img1 = image1.getImage();
        Image newImage = img1.getScaledInstance(144, 144,     Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon after = new ImageIcon(newImage);
        btnPic1.setIcon(after);
        btnPic1.setText("");
        FirstName1.setVisible(true);
        LastName1.setVisible(true);
        btnPic1.setVisible(true);
        MiddleName1.setVisible(true);
        }
```

In my data the image stored here is null.

```
if(rs.next()){
        rs.absolute(2);
        FirstName2.setText(rs.getString("cFirstname"));
        LastName2.setText(rs.getString("CLastname"));
        MiddleName2.setText(rs.getString("cmiddlename"));
        BufferedImage im2 = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("cimage"));
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(im2);
        Image img2 = image2.getImage();
        Image newImage2 = img2.getScaledInstance(144, 144, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon after2 = new ImageIcon(newImage2);
        btnPic2.setIcon(after2);
        btnPic2.setText("");
        FirstName2.setVisible(true);
        LastName2.setVisible(true);
        btnPic2.setVisible(true);
        MiddleName2.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Then my program doesn't do this and onwards.

```
if(rs.next()){
        rs.absolute(3);
        FirstName3.setText(rs.getString("cFirstname"));
        LastName3.setText(rs.getString("CLastname"));
        MiddleName3.setText(rs.getString("cmiddlename"));
        BufferedImage im3 = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("cimage"));
        ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon(im3);
        Image img3 = image3.getImage();
        Image newImage3 = img3.getScaledInstance(144, 144, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon after3 = new ImageIcon(newImage3);
        btnPic3.setIcon(after3);
        btnPic3.setText("");
        FirstName3.setVisible(true);
        LastName3.setVisible(true);
        btnPic3.setVisible(true);
        MiddleName3.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in java programming. How will I add "skip line if null" Can you be more accurate in coding. Thanks!

Comment: `"How will I add "skip line if null""`!! -- You don't want to do GUI and database programming if you're not yet familiar with basic Java such as use of if/else control structures. Otherwise you're in for a painful slog.

Comment: @YassinHH Thank you. It helps for my program.

Comment: @ZeroSerum you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result code would be something like this

```
if(rs.next()){
        rs.absolute(2);
        FirstName2.setText(rs.getString("cFirstname"));
        LastName2.setText(rs.getString("CLastname"));
        MiddleName2.setText(rs.getString("cmiddlename"));
            if(rs.getBinaryStream("cimage")!=null){
            BufferedImage im2 = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("cimage"));
            ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(im2);
            Image img2 = image2.getImage();
            Image newImage2 = img2.getScaledInstance(144, 144, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon after2 = new ImageIcon(newImage2);
        btnPic2.setIcon(after2);
        btnPic2.setText("");}
            else{
            btnPic2.setText("No Picture");     
            }
        FirstName2.setVisible(true);
        LastName2.setVisible(true);
        btnPic2.setVisible(true);
        MiddleName2.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Adding a "if null" statement. Although in this use. I reverse it. Thank you for the comments and answers. I have been able to come up with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Which line throws the IllegalArgumentException? Perhaps I'm being over-simplistic, but a simple solution could be that you check for a null image variable immediately before this line, and if the variable is null, don't use it, and skip that line(s). A better solution is to find out why the images are null and to prevent this from happening in the first place.

Comment: For your question why the image is null. It is null because it isn't been set.
Is it better if there will be a default image so that I will never be null?

Comment: @ZeroSerum: absolutely.